# Can I Share My Cable Internet Connection Through my ADSL Wireless modem + Router

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, internet-connection, adsl, cable-modem

At first I want to say this question can be found by googling but I cannot find any satisfactory answer. So I am posting it here.

I have a ZTE-ZXDSL-531 ADSL Modem. At first I used an ADSL broadband & I could connect multiple devices in wireless to the internet using the modem. So I think this is a hybrid modem with router. (Please correct me if I am wrong).

Now I have switched to cable broadband (you know which comes with a co-axial CAT 5 cable with a RJ45, which is connected directly to computer cabinet).

My question is it possible to share this cable internet connection with this hybrid modem? If not please give me the reason.

If possible how to connect it & how to configure the modem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide an example of answer that isn't satisfactory.  Your DSL modem simply had multiple ports.  You can purchase a cable modem with multiple ports also.  You just can't use your DSL modem as a router itself.

Answer (score 2):

You probably can't use it as a wireless router, but you could try looking in the config options for DHCP settings.

If you could disable DHCP server in the device, then connect the cable you get the internet from - to one of four lan ports in ZTE. It could work as a "wireless switch" but that depends on the device software.

Alternatively you can browse the settings and try different work modes for this device.

Answer (score 0):

There will be a problem of disconnection when multiple devices are connected to the router. You'll need to assign IP addresses to each new device connecting to the router.

In Windows you can do it using the Network Manager. In Android long pressing on the WiFi network (aim the WiFi setting menu) gives you an option to customize or change the settings.

Using cmd find the default gateway by using 'ipconfig/all' command. It will generally be 192.168.1.1 So you should assign IP addresses with values 192.168.1.x where x is unique for each device. Since this is a static IP address, you have to enter the network configuration individually to all your devices, that you intend to use in the range of this particular Wifi network.